# Completar campos com select

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou com um problema, que não consigo mais resolver, estou tentando preencher os campo a partir de uma opção que esta contida dentro de um `select` que é preenchida automaticamente com o `foreach`, porem não está funcionando

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    // Tratando o objeto de manipulacao DOM
    const select = document.getElementById("cliente");
    const state = document.getElementById("estado");

    // Trata o evento change do select
    select.addEventListener("change", function(event)
    {
        // Obtem o option que foi selecionado
        let _selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

        // Obtem o valor da propriedade data-state
        let _state = _selectedOption.getAttribute("data-state");

        // Atualiza o valor do campo estado
        state.value = _state;
    });


</script>


<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

    <!-- Cliente -->
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <!-- Legenda -->
        <label for="clientes" class="label label-primary">Cliente</label>

        <!-- Campo -->
        <select name="cliente" id="cliente" class="form-control">
            <?php
            foreach ($clientes as $cliente)
            {
                ?>
                    <!-- Opcoes -->
                    <option value="<?= $cliente['id'] ?>" data-state="<?= $cliente['estado'] ?>"> <?= $cliente['nome'] ?> </option>

                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Data do pedido -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <!-- Legenda -->
        <label for="dataPedido" class="label label-primary">Data do Pedido</label>

        <!-- Legenda -->
        <input type="text" name="dataPedido" id="dataPedido" class="form-control text-center" readonly="" value="<?= date("d/M/Y")?>">
    </div>

    <!-- Estado -->
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <!-- Legenda -->
        <label for="estado" class="label label-primary">Estado</label>

        <!-- Campo -->
        <input type="text" name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control text-center" readonly="">
    </div>
</form>
```

Quero que quando eu selecinar um opção do `select`, o campo estado e outros campos que virão futuramente, sejam preenchidos com os respectivos valores. A propriedade `data-state` armazena o estado e futuramente serão criadas novas propriedades para armazenar os valores dos próximos campos.

Comment: E o que está acontecendo atualmente quando você seleciona uma cliente? Aparece algum erro no console?

Comment: ele aparece duas mensagens: TypeError: select is null[Learn More]  e O método getPreventDefault() não deve mais ser usado. No lugar, use defaultPrevented.

Comment: Rodrigo: tens esse `script` na página assim como está na pergunta? Nesse caso tens de o colocar depois do HTML, para o JavaScript encontrar o HTML.

Comment: Essa eu não sabia, achei que o script na frente faria funcionar do mesmo jeito, agora funcionou. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**O problema:**

Quando o JavaScript é corrido ele vai procurar os pedaços de HTML que precisa, mas uma vez que o Browser processa a página aos bocados à medida que ela vai sendo recebida do servidor ele não espera por ter o conteúdo todo.

Isso quer dizer que quando o JavaScript é lido tudo o que vem depois no texto do código ainda não é conhecido pelo Browser.

Assim no  momento do parse do código JavaScript o HTML ainda não existe aos olhos do Browser e `const select = document.getElementById("cliente");` vai dar `null`.

**Solução:**

Coloca esse script no final do HTML, antes do fecho da tag `</body>`.

Outra alternativa é dizer ao JavaScript que só deve correr o código quando o carregamento da página estiver completo:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // Tratando o objeto de manipulacao DOM
    const select = document.getElementById("cliente");
    const state = document.getElementById("estado");

    // Trata o evento change do select
    select.addEventListener("change", function(event){
        // Obtem o option que foi selecionado
        let _selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
        // Obtem o valor da propriedade data-state
        let _state = _selectedOption.getAttribute("data-state");
        // Atualiza o valor do campo estado
        state.value = _state;
    });
}
```